# What probabilty density do I use with poisson processes?

Tags: statistics

For this question:

> Given a poisson process with on the avg "a" arrivals per unit time,
>   find the probability that there will be no arrivals during a time
>   interval of length t, namely, the probability that the waiting times
>   between successive arrivals will be at least of length t.

What probability density would I use for this of which I could use to solve the question? Thanks!

Comment: **Hint**: What is the distribution of the number of arrivals in $[0,t]$ for a Poisson process with $a$ arrivals (on average) per unit time? Now, what is the probability that the associated random variable takes on a value of zero?

Comment: (I also think that whoever worded that question like that should really give it another shot; the part from *namely...* on could definitely be stated more clearly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the distribution for the waiting time between events of a poisson process.
$W$ has  exponential distribution with parameter $ \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the average number of events per unit time for the Poisson process.

---

This isn't hard to see. If $X$ is the number of events occurring in the interval $[0,t]$, then
$P[W>t]=P[X=0]= e^{-\lambda t}$. So the cdf of $W$ is $F_W(t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}, t\ge0$; whence the density of $W$ is $f_W(t)= \lambda e^{-\lambda t}, t\ge 0$.

Comment: i don't get why P[X=0] = e^-λt. From the wiki, the probability is the λe^λx, how did you get that? Thanks.

Comment: $X$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$. So $X=0$ is the event that no events occur in the interval $[0,t]$. This is the same as $P[W>t]$, where $W$ is the waiting time. Note, I first found the cumulative density, $F_W$, of $W$ first, then differentiated to get the density (though I didn't explicitly say so).

Answer (score 0):

The exponential distribution.

[Exponential Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)